# What's the usage of ばかり in "見たこと無いものばかりだわ！"?

Tags: grammar

I've got a feeling it's an intensifier for the statement, but I want to be certain about the grammatical stuff behind it, since I've only seen one mention of that in all of my materials and research

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what the context of the sentence is, but it means "only".  And I feel like it's a little stronger than if it were to use だけ.

> 見たことないものばかりだわ！　→　(There are) Only things I've never seen before (here)!

Answer (score 0):

> 見たことないもの**ばかりだ**わ！

Every thing here are what I've never seen before **without exception!**