# Noun+ばかりであるから+... with no subject

Tags: grammar, particle-ばかり

In the following sentence,

> このように来る者拒まず、本人確認を行うことなく貸し付ける懐の深い金融会社ばかりであるから、取り立ても熱烈なのだ。

as far as I understand, the whole part before ばかり is, grammatically, a noun, say:

> そんな会社ばかりであるから、取り立ても熱烈なのだ。

But then, I don't understand this usage of ばかり. Maybe ばかりであるから means something like だけあって or だから当然 ? But then, isn't a *subject* lacking?

The subject could be the topic from the previous sentence, but from context I don't see how it would make sense. This is a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1soJ7RaE1kvfytEDeDgQsThBcb9FNSXcM/view?usp=sharing) to the page this text was taken from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ばかりだ has many usages, but this type of ばかり is almost the same as だけ in terms of both meaning and grammar. Here it means "only", "all" or "nothing but". The subject is  これら(の会社) (or "they" or "these companies"), which has been simply omitted.

- 会社である。
  They are companies.
- 会社**ばかり**である。 ∼ 会社**だけ**である。
  They are **all** (such-and-such) companies.
- 会社**ばかり**であるから…
  Since they are all (such-and-such) companies...
- このように{[来る者拒まず、本人確認を行うことなく貸し付ける▶][懐の深い金融会社]}**ばかり**であるから…
  As such, since they are all "broad-minded" financial companies that welcome everyone and lend money without verifying their identity...
  <sub>(懐の深い is a positive expression and is being used sarcastically here.)</sub>

Related: [What's the usage of ばかり in "見たこと無いものばかりだわ！"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/47740/5010)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the meaning of ばかり here.
Still, I'm surprised the subject can be omitted in this context, because "these companies" were not really the topic of the discourse. I've added a link to the full paragraph in the question. Could you have a look and confirm that sounds natural to you?

Comment: @StephaneC Yes I can confirm the implied subject is 十数社. The implicit subject is not necessarily the same as that in the last sentence.